# Linux distribution for my home theater

Tags: linux, firmware

I bought mini-pc and I plan to install linux on it. My first choice would be the Ubuntu distribution. I plan to use it for playing videos, ssh access, network/wifi (router) and running flash (not browser, native app) files. So... linux as "firmware" for my small pc box.

What distribution would you propose?

Comment: Well, this question is certainly in the wrong place. Migrate to [Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Vote to close, off topic.

Answer (score 1):

[Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) is a community supported add-on for Ubuntu focused upon setting up a standalone MythTV based PVR system.  This is probably exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 for Mythbuntu. I've normally used that, then disabled mythtv from auto starting, and get XBMC to auto start instead. The UI is much nicer and can still connect to MythTV backend if you're doing that.